# How to Display ASP Gridiew Empty Data Text after Clicking Search Button

Tags: asp.net

Pls Help Me
The problem here is that i want the empty data template to be Display after the button search has been click but right now every time i open the page, it will show the empty data template before do any searching ....

Comment: Presumably you are binding the gridview in a function that runs every time the page is called. You need to make sure that the first time on the page (using if(!isPostBack) in Page_Load), the code that populates the gridview is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//put ur gridview connection here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    grid1.DataSource = sqlboxfile;
    DataBind();
    grid2.Visible = false;
}
```